# Cannot find name "offsetHeight" or "clientHeight" on a React/Next.js TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a custom collapsible FAQ component that is based on the height of the element when it's expanded and vice versa.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default FAQItem({title, description}: FAQItemProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const heightRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const collapsible = () => (!isOpen ? setIsOpen(true) : setIsOpen(false));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    !isOpen
      ? (heightRef.current!.style.height = "96px")
      : (heightRef.current!.style.height = `${offsetHeight}px`)
  }, [isOpen]);

  return(
    <div ref={heightRef}>
      <h2 onClick={collapsible}>{title}</h2>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Because I'm dealing with TypeScript, some of the already answered solutions I could find unfortunately doesn't have anything TypeScript-related answered and won't fly with TS and had to add type definitions. And it returned with error `Cannot find name "offsetHeight".`, and `clientHeight` does the same thing too.

I've tried adding `any` to offsetHeight, including:

```
declare const window: Window & typeof globalThis & {
  offsetHeight: number | any;
}
```

...and as expected, the error went away but it didn't work - the height *didn't* change and and won't expand.

Nevertheless, all the solutions I could find unfortunately has no TypeScript-related answers regarding getting the width or height of an element on a React TypeScript project - all of them are just plain React questions without TypeScript, and I prefer to not use any external libraries of any kind either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because you haven't defined the variables `offsetHeight` and `clientHeight`. Now, I know you don't need to define them, but because your usage is improper, the compiler thinks you forgot to create these variables.

Here's what you want: `heightRef.current?.clientHeight` and `heightRef.current?.offsetHeight`, the `?` is just to avoid errors in case the `ref` is not loaded.

#### Edit with code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const heightRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const collapsible = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  console.log(isOpen, heightRef.current?.style?.height);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      heightRef.current?.style.height = `${heightRef.current?.offsetHeight}px`;
    } else {
      heightRef.current?.style.height = "96px";
    }
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={heightRef} style={{height: 1100}}>
      <h1 onClick={collapsible}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please accept the answer if it helps! Thank you!

Comment: Also you could avoid the possibility of a `null`/`undefined` error by using the `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`. It works similar to `useEffect` but is executed only after the DOM is loaded, which means `ref` cannot be null.

Comment: Ooh, I see! It took me a while to realize that I'm probably defining it as a value as I'm used to primitive JS DOM code. And I've tried your solution, I got a diff. error as I wrapped it with a `useState` saying that type `undefined` isn't assignable to `SetStateAction<number>` instead. Even `heightRef.current?.clientHeight!` barely changes the UI.

Comment: Did you mean to say `useLayoutEffect` and not `useState`?

Comment: Well the thing is, I'm working on a Next.js app, and it would complain when I used `useLayoutEffect` about server UI hydration and whatnot - so I had to stick to `useEffect` instead; and I'm using another `useState` to change the height value, as the first `useState` is to handle expand/collapsing the element

Comment: Can you share that code? Preferably as a different issue and link it here. Also accept this answer if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: It's not the same code I've provided but it should be similar: https://github.com/skepfusky/skepfusky.xyz/blob/v5-contentful/src/components/home/PreviousWorks.tsx#L25-L57

Comment: Since you are using `useEffect`, the block inside the same gets executed before the DOM, and therefore `heightRef` is not yet assigned. You could do this: `setCurrentHeight(heightRef.current?.clientHeight || 96)`

Comment: I tried your solution, but it won't expand, changing from `clientWidth` *did* expand, but never `clientHeight` - I pushed my changes and the UI won't react, I console.log'd the thing and it does work, but it won't expand for whatever reason.

Comment: you can use `useLayoutEffect` with nextjs if you make the hook isomorphic to appease the server. Instead of passing `typeof window !== "undefined" ? useLayoutEffect : useEffect` replace the latter with a Noop `() => {}` to suppress hydration warnings. 

`export const useIsomorphicLayoutEffect =
  typeof window !== "undefined" ? React.useLayoutEffect : () => {};`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't defined the offsetHeight variable yet referencing it here

```
(heightRef.current!.style.height = '${offsetHeight}px')
```

it's why typescript is yelling. Although we don't need to define this, instead grab the value by doing this `heightRef.current.offsetHeight` .

Also instead of assigning like this `heightRef.current!.style.height = "96px"` do this `(heightRef.current?.style.height = "96px")`. As far as I know, there is no such operator `!.` in javascript.